# Apk size becomes smaller and corrupted with nothing changed inGithub Actions

Tags: xamarin.forms, msbuild, apk, github-actions, nuget-package-restore

We use GA for CI/CD in Xamarin.Forms solution to deliver Android apks. It was restoring/building release apk 37MB size up to 25st of August 2020. Everything was working perfect at least at 21st of August. But starting from 25st of August size of built apk was 24.8MB and this apk became corrupted. The problem is still actual at the moment. We changed nothing that can result size reducing and apk corruption.

```
    - name: Add msbuild to PATH
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.0.0
    - uses: nuget/setup-nuget@v1
 
    - name: Droid nuget restore and build
      run: |
        nuget restore
        cd MySolution
        cd MySolution.Droid
        msbuild MySolution.Droid.csproj /verbosity:normal /t:SignAndroidPackage /p:Configuration=Release
```

If I execute exactly the same command from a command line on my local Windows machine, apk builds correctly and has 37MB size. So currently I have no idea how to fix this issue. [logs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Jq9ZobdFg7IlEo6q2EfUN7R6vOcQ3UVw7QW2GKQxz6I/edit?usp=sharing) [droid.csproj](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XlSCLt5M3YI5SXLzD2HFA3WBMmeM6Kt-/view?usp=sharing)

Upload Release folder as an artifact:

```
- uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
     name: my-artifact
     path: MySolution/MySolution.Droid/bin/Release
```

Comment: Share the logs of the build using a pastebin

Comment: @Saamer added logs in the description

Comment: Please use a pastebin to make it easier. Could you share the Droid.csproj file as well? Do you have the pro guard needed? Can you try to disable the code shrinker and see if you have the same issue? After the build, how do publish the archive?

Comment: @Saamer currently i am not able to use pastebin. It is too many lines of logs form free version. Edited question and attached droid.csproj. Seems proguard is inactive. Set linking to None. It helped and now working. But apk size is now 54MB instead of 37MB. So problem was with linking. Is it possible to setup linking properly somehow to reduce size?

Comment: Was it set to Link SDK assemblies only before? Could you please share the step after your build step?

Comment: @Saamer Yes. It was set to Link SDK assemblies only before. Edited question. Now it has upload step with all bin/release content

Answer (score 1):

I set linking to None in android project properties. Now apk is not corrupted and installing well. But size increased from 37MB to 54MB. So it resolved my problem but not perfect